# Delombok - InvocationTargetException with JDK 1.7

Tags: java, java-7, lombok

I'm using [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) to generate getters, setters, hashCode, equlas & toString programmatically. I'm working with Eclipse luna. The code works perfectly fine with `JDK 1.8`, but when I'm degrading the version to `JDK 1.7`, its throwing the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at lombok.launch.Delombok.delombok(Delombok.java:50)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NATIVE_HEADER_OUTPUT
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.initHandlers(Locations.java:654)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.<init>(Locations.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BaseFileManager.createLocations(BaseFileManager.java:85)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BaseFileManager.<init>(BaseFileManager.java:71)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.<init>(JavacFileManager.java:125)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$1.make(JavacFileManager.java:115)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$1.make(JavacFileManager.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.get(Context.java:150)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.get(Context.java:193)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.<init>(Enter.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.instance(Enter.java:115)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.<init>(MemberEnter.java:101)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.instance(MemberEnter.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.<init>(Attr.java:115)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.instance(Attr.java:102)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.<init>(Resolve.java:122)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.instance(Resolve.java:158)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.<init>(Check.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.instance(Check.java:99)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.<init>(Types.java:118)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.instance(Types.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:291)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.instance(ClassReader.java:253)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.<init>(JavaCompiler.java:348)
    at lombok.javac.CommentCatcher.create(CommentCatcher.java:40)
    at lombok.delombok.Delombok.delombok(Delombok.java:479)
    ... 9 more
```

My maven dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone please put some light on it?

Comment: Does this issue arise even when using a simple hello world program using the pom including the dependencies above, thus not having any real dependency from within the code? Is this a build-time error or a run-time error?

Comment: It's a run-time error. The build is fine. I googled a bit now and found out that `NATIVE_HEADER_OUTPUT` has been introduced in `JDK 1.8`, hence throwing the error I mentioned. But I'm not able to find how to fix it. :(